# PHP: Selection of text between two tags with help of regular expression

Tags: php, expression, selection

I got this regular expression for selection of text between tags.

```
preg_match_all('/<t>(.*?)<\/t>/s', $text, $match);
```

what I need is to edit this expression so it would select the text only if it is at least 3 characters long... Is it possible? If yes, how?

Comment: Note that if you have another `<t></t>` nested within this one, you will have a very hard time finding out with regular expressions. See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: Fortunately this case shouldn´t occur, so it should be ok :)

Comment: Maybe http://www.regexr.com can come in handy :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
'/<t>(.{3,}?)<\/t>/s'
```

Comment: -1: This will match 0, 3, 6, ... characters. Also, I don't think there's a difference between `*?` and just `*`.

Comment: `A Similar useful`[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5527191/regular-expression-for-a-string-that-must-contain-minimum-14-characters-where-a)

Comment: Almost right, but it also matches the empty string now, because of the question mark. If you remove that, it will be ok.

Comment: Thanks, it looks fine :) But I met one problem...in some cases there is <t> m2</t> for example....so this will be selected too...but if i rewrite {3,} to {4,}, it won´t select some words I need.... Is there something like trim() in regex?

Comment: @MichalSirůček : read [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1364974/php-regular-expression-to-remove-tags-in-html-document) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/758806/php-regex-to-remove-html)

Comment: @MichalSirůček And try this also `'/<t>(.{3,})<\/t>/s'` as Mr. Spiny says.

Comment: Unfortunately this isn´t working right also...I tried to remove question mark too...

Comment: @MichalSirůček You just want to strip tags ? Use `strip_tags` function Link is [here](php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) .....Although `'/<t>(.{3,})<\/t>/s'` should work!

Comment: No, if I´d strip all the tags, it would be messy, I think...Some tags I don´t need at all, thats why I select only some and even in them I want only some.

Comment: Although previous should work try this one also `'/<t>(.){3,}<\/t>/s'`  ...And here is quick tutorial for [PHP regular expressions](http://www.macronimous.com/resources/writing_regular_expression_with_php.asp)

Comment: I think there is some other problem at my side....Anyway thanks for the links! I´ll check it out.

Comment: Sorry buddy!... at the last I feel you should also try this `'/<t>.{3,}<\/t>/s'`. I can't understand what is problem? Sorry!

Comment: It´s okay, don´t worry :) I solved problem in not very elegant way, I just deleted the tags and text which I still didn´t want with help of preg_replace...I think my code is just messed up :D But it works now, thats important :D

Answer (score 2):

```
preg_match_all('/<t>(.{3,}?)<\/t>/s', $text, $match);
```