# Remove everything within script and style tags

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, regex

I have a variable named `$articleText` and it contains html code. There are `script` and `style` codes within `<script>` and `<style>` html elements. I want to scan the `$articleText` and remove these pieces of code. If I can also remove the actual html elements `<script>`, `</script>`, `<style>` and `</style>`, I would do that too.

I imagine I need to be using regex however I am not skilled in it.

Can anyone assist?

I wish I could provide some code but like I said I am not skilled in regex so I don't have anything to show.

#### I cannot use DOM. I need specifically to use regex against these specific tags

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/758806/php-regex-to-remove-html

Comment: @ScottHelme I need it to be specifically these tags

Comment: @jkushner easy [`(?s)<(script|style)[^>]*>.*?</\1>`](http://regex101.com/r/tL3nA7)

Comment: [strip_tags()](http://php.net/strip_tags)?

Comment: Your note about "cannot use DOM" needs to be justified. DOM is how to do this. RegEx is simply not the appropriate tool, despite the fact that some here will advise that you use it. Do not use RegEx on HTML! Do not use RegEx on HTML! Do not use RegEx on HTML! It cannot be said enough.

Comment: For all those who think that it's impossible for regex to be in harmony with html, here comes a solution from the anti-naysayers departement `<(?P<tagname>style|script)[^>]*>(?:(?:(?!<(?&tagname)[^>]*>|</(?&tagname)>).)|(?R))*</(?&tagname)>`. See a [demo](http://regex101.com/r/xK0vZ5) with some explanation. Break it with valid html and I'll reward you with 50 rep (bounty) on one answer.

Comment: @HamZa - test it with `<style> <!-- </style> --> *{ display: none } </style>`

Comment: @Ωmega gotta keep [my promise](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11874234) lol

Comment: @Ωmega In 2 days and I can award it, but don't worry I'll wait 7 days so that your answer would get "attention". You'll most likely get more upvotes. Meanwhile I fixed that [hack of yours](http://regex101.com/r/kD1iJ8), ofc I need to think about `/* */` and other means of destruction ...

Comment: @HamZa - next test is `<style data-text="></style>"> * { margin: 0 } </style>`

Comment: @HamZa Out of curiosity, why try so hard to do that which is fundamentally bad practice? You thought you had it locked down and Omega broke it in one go. That will keep happening, over and over and over. That is **why** one simply doesn't use RegEx on HTML. The advisory against it isn't cargo cult programming, it is based on the fact that you are discovering the hard way -- there are too many potential gotchyas because HTML is not a regular language.

Comment: @Chris because I keep hearing `you can't parse html with regex`. This statement is just misleading. It's indeed true in a wild environment where you don't know what you exactly are expecting, but in some cases it's just doable, especially in those simple cases. Now I'm just showing that you can parse nested structures with modern regex. I'll maybe think about those nasty hacks and come with a better one (for fun && experience). And yes, I do use html parsers  if necessary :)

Comment: @HamZa I say it right in my profile: I am against using Really Cool Thing X because it "does all the stuff for you!!!111", buuut.... in this case, DomDocument is a really cool thing. As long as your work on this is in the spirit of fun and learning, then I approve. [sarcasm]I know that my approval is pretty important to you[/sarcasm] :P

Comment: @HamZa regarding [demo 1](http://regex101.com/r/xK0vZ5) and [demo 2](http://regex101.com/r/kD1iJ8), i can sneak this guy by (totally valid): `<style> *{ display: none } </style attr>`. Of course there is a simple fix... but, just sayin' :S like @Chris says, no sense it working hard for all the edge cases when a now simple (relatively speaking) HTML parser will do - is it worth the time!?

Comment: @zamnuts since when is `</style attr>` valid html ? I've intentionally imposed this rule. -- It's worth the time to train my regex-fu

Comment: @HamZa totally valid. go ahead, pop it any modern browser. you can't assume cracks are always going to follow the rules, that's the nature of a crack!

Comment: @HamZa here's another: `<style>*{display:none;}` ... omit the closing tag. again invalid, but if there's isn't a style tag somewhere down the line, the site is borked. _I want my 50 rep._

Comment: @zamnuts what I meant by valid html is valid by the specs. See [w3](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/syntax.html#end-tags), it seems that I need to add `\s*` in `</(?&tagname)\s*>`. Anything other than the specified standard isn't valid html. Browsers do have a robust dom parsers and they could even correct those silly errors. That's way out of the scope of regex IMO. And don't worry, like I mentioned, I do use html parsers.

Comment: @zamnuts omitting the closing tag isn't valid html since `<style>` ins't a self-closing tag, out of scope. I mentioned `Break it with valid html`. And don't worry, if you find a way out, I will reward it

Comment: @HamZa - How about `<script>var s = "<script>";</script>`, `<!-- <style></style> -->`, or `<i title="<style></style>"></i>`? A cheap shot is `<script></script >`, but that one is just an exploit. All of these are valid, of course (`var s = "</script>";` is *not* valid, by the way). This looks like a good place to [plug my answer on Regex and HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6752487/7586), where I tried to agree with everything you said in the comments.

Comment: @Kobi nice answer +1. I'm totally aware of those techniques you just mentioned, someone tried to take 50 rep by using `var variable = "</script>";`.

Comment: @HamZa - That would make them thieves and liars because it *does* close the `<script>` tag. Anyway, Thanks! `:)` (also, go answer some questions, you need to recover points)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Do not use RegEx on HTML. PHP provides a tool for parsing DOM structures, called appropriately DomDocument.

```
<?php
// some HTML for example
$myHtml = '<html><head><script>alert("hi mom!");</script></head><body><style>body { color: red;} </style><h1>This is some content</h1><p>content is awesome</p></body><script src="someFile.js"></script></html>';

// create a new DomDocument object
$doc = new DOMDocument();

// load the HTML into the DomDocument object (this would be your source HTML)
$doc->loadHTML($myHtml);

removeElementsByTagName('script', $doc);
removeElementsByTagName('style', $doc);
removeElementsByTagName('link', $doc);

// output cleaned html
echo $doc->saveHtml();

function removeElementsByTagName($tagName, $document) {
  $nodeList = $document->getElementsByTagName($tagName);
  for ($nodeIdx = $nodeList->length; --$nodeIdx >= 0; ) {
    $node = $nodeList->item($nodeIdx);
    $node->parentNode->removeChild($node);
  }
}
```

You can try it here: https://eval.in/private/4f225fa0dcb4eb

**Documentation**

- `DomDocument` - http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php
- `DomNodeList` - http://php.net/manual/en/class.domnodelist.php
- `DomDocument::getElementsByTagName` - https://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementsbytagname.php

Comment: this doesn't get the last script tag... only the first occurrence.

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: Note that this breaks DOMDocument parsing when using loadHTML() because of the HTML markup in a Javascript string:

```<div>
 <script>
 var str = '</div>this does NOT get removed';
 </script>
</div>```

Answer (score 29):

Even regex is not a good tool for this kind of task, for small simple task it may work.

---

If you want to remove just inner text of tag(s), use:

```
preg_replace('/(<(script|style)\b[^>]*>).*?(<\/\2>)/is', "$1$3", $txt);
```

See demo **[here](http://ideone.com/ukX5P3)**.

If you want to remove also tags, replacement string in the above code would be empty, so just `""`.

Comment: It seems that someone is downvoting all regex answers, my condolences

Comment: Yeah, that's a shame, particularly as the questioner is specifically asking for a regex answer.

Comment: @HamZa - I get used to it. Couple minus points don't make difference in my reputation. OP is asking for regex solution, so I offered him one. My answer clearly says that regex is not right tool, so I think the downvoter is even bad reader, or just one of those angry guys :)

Comment: If the OP asked how to do this without using the letter "e" in his code, would you attempt it? Not a downvoter, but I do not understand why anyone would knowingly provide a bad answer just to meet the arbitrary and probably mistaken constraints put forward by an inexperienced asker.

Comment: @Chris - That would be silly. OP may have reason why want to use regex and not DOM. For example (s)he may not have such DOM library available in his hosting account and has no chance to install it. I am just trying to help, that's it.

Comment: Sure, I get it. But without some kind of justification, "I can't use DOM" is as valid as "I can't use the letter 'e'" -- silly artificial restriction. When someone asks, "how do I do this with ______", one of my first questions is, "do you even need to use ______"? Many times, the asker doesn't know something better exists, or has a mistaken idea that it is too difficult to work with. Meh. Again, downvotes are probably not merited, but I got a DV too so I suspect someone is trying to be "strategic".

Comment: @Chris - I got your point as well. Certainly, OP should be more specific in his/her post. Ironic is that his/her post gets (so far) no downvote, but I see so many downvotes for answers.

Comment: @Ωmega your regex fails for: `<script>document.write("bad stuff</script>");now you see me</script>` produces: `<script></script>");now you see me</script>` :( in some cases this could still serve its purpose.

Comment: @zamnuts - Yup. Did you read first line in my answer? "...for small simple task..."

Comment: just make the regex '.../is' since people do write <SCRIPT...>

Comment: How do I remove just the tags and not the content?

Comment: @3zzy - Use `preg_replace('/(<(script|style)\b[^>]*>)(.*?)(<\/\2>)/is', "$3", $txt);`

Comment: This is  a perfectly valid answer IMO. Script and style tags never have any nested tags and coincidentally they are the only tags that you'll want to remove with content when converting HTML to plaintext. For others you can use `strip_tags`.

Comment: It works for me too. Can someone explain this in detail, I can't understand what this really means?

Answer (score 4):

I think this should do what you need (assuming there are no nested script and style tags):

```
preg_replace('/(<script[^>]*>.+?<\/script>|<style[^>]*>.+?<\/style>)/is', '', $articleText);
```

Comment: There is no `g` modifier in PHP. While matching, you have `preg_match()` which will match only the first occurence. In other languages like javascript, you use the `g` modifier to match all. In php, you just use another function `preg_match_all()`. Now how about replacing ? Well `preg_replace()` replaces everything by default. You could add a 4th parameter to limit it.

Comment: Sorry, I'm too used to writing javascript regex. I've updated the answer.

Comment: I forgot something important, don't forget to use reluctant (ungreedy) quantifiers. Replace `.+` with `.+?`. Anyways +1 :)

Answer (score 2):

Here's sample data:

```
$in = '
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">window.location="somehwere";</script>
        <style>
            .someCSS {border:1px solid black;}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>....</p>
        <div>
            <script type="text/javascript">document.write("bad stuff");</script>
        </div>
        <ul>
            <li><style type="text/css">#moreCSS {font-weight:900;}</style></li>
        </ul>
    </body>
</html>';
```

And now the spelled-out version:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0','UTF-8');
$dom->loadHTML($in);

removeByTag($dom,'style');
removeByTag($dom,'script');

var_dump($dom->saveHTML());

function removeByTag($dom,$tag) {
    $nodeList = $dom->getElementsByTagName($tag);
    removeAll($nodeList);
}

function removeAll($nodeList) {
    for ( $i = $nodeList->length; --$i >=0; ) {
        removeSelf($nodeList->item($i));
    }
}

function removeSelf($node) {
    $node->parentNode->removeChild($node);
}
```

And an alternate (does the same thing, just no function declarations):

```
$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0','UTF-8');
$dom->loadHTML($in);

for ( $list = $dom->getElementsByTagName('script'), $i = $list->length; --$i >=0; ) {
    $node = $list->item($i);
    $node->parentNode->removeChild($node);
}

for ( $list = $dom->getElementsByTagName('style'), $i = $list->length; --$i >=0; ) {
    $node = $list->item($i);
    $node->parentNode->removeChild($node);
}

var_dump($dom->saveHTML());
```

The trick is to [iterate *backwards* when deleting nodes](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domnodelist.php#83390). And getElementsByTagName will traverse the entire DOM for you, so you don't have to (none of that hasChildNodes, nextSibling, nextChild stuff).

Perhaps the best solution is somewhere in between those two extreme examples.

---

Couldn't help myself, this is probably the best version of my suggestions. It doesn't include an incrementor (`$i`) to muck things up, and removes from the bottom-up:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0','UTF-8');
$dom->loadHTML($in);

removeElementsByTagName($dom,'script');
removeElementsByTagName($dom,'style');

function removeElementsByTagName($dom,$tagName) {
    $list = $dom->getElementsByTagName($tagName);
    while ( $node = $list->item(0) ) {
        $node->parentNode->removeChild($node);
    }
}

var_dump($dom->saveHTML());
```

As you remove nodes, they get moved up in the child list of the parent, so 1 becomes 0 and 2 becomes 1, etc. Keep doing this (`while`) until there aren't anymore ([`->item` returns null](https://www.php.net/manual/en/domnodelist.item.php)). Also wrapped this in a reusable function.

Comment: The second parameter is about **allowable tags**. This is the inverse what he wants ...

Comment: @HamZa totally slipped my mind on that one, updated w/ a proper answer.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this is both a concern of not letting your design get messed up by random styles as well as secure your site from user scripting, removing these tags will not alone keep you safe.

Consider the case of [event attributes](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_eventattributes.asp) (ex: onmouseover, onclick):

```
<h1 onclick="console.log('user made this happen');">User Scripting Test</h1>
```

or even worse

```
<h1 onclick='function addCSSRule(a,b,c,d){"insertRule"in a?a.insertRule(b+"{"+c+"}",d):"addRule"in a&&a.addRule(b,c,d)}var style=document.createElement("style");style.appendChild(document.createTextNode("")),document.head.appendChild(style),sheet=style.sheet,addCSSRule(sheet,"*","color: #ff0!important");'>Messing with your styles!</h1>
```

With this, it's fairly trivial to start inserting all sorts of stuff into the document.

Last example of stylesheet mods taken from David Walsh -https://davidwalsh.name/add-rules-stylesheets

#### The only solution

... is to use a proven third-party library that specializes in this. I suggest [HTML Purifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/docs). It'll rid your user input of styles, scripts, and pesky event attributes.

Answer (score 0):

A regex to do this would be incredibly obtuse, because of the possibility of tags within tags, and such confounding constructs like tag attributes.

I would suggest doing this in a DOM (either in PHP or JavaScript), which can identify and remove the undesired tags through actual parsing.

Comment: I cannot. It must be a regex that scans specifically for these tags only. There shouldn't be nested tags in a script or style tag

Comment: @jkushner, yes... just traverse the DOMDocument and remove the DOMNode/DOMElement objects that match tagName "script" and "style"

Comment: @zamnuts that sounds excellent. can you make an answer providing this code?

Comment: @jkushner Could you provide us with a reason why it **must** be regex?

Comment: @MackieeE I didnt know you can do what zamnuts said. Thats a good solution. Id like to see that in action.

Comment: @zamnuts i see. can you show me how to do this by removing domnodes/domelements

Comment: @jkushner http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15272726/how-to-delete-element-with-domdocument

Comment: @jkushner I have demonstrated using DomDocument --- do not use RegEx! :)