# Regex - how to match a chain of words until a non "word" character

Tags: php, regex

I have a string similar to this one:

> This is a test string - This is a second test string ; This is a third test string

My goal is to match the first chain of characters only:

> This is a test string

The separator can be anything except a word: (-, ;, _, ? etc....)

How can I do that with a regex?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
/([a-z\d\s]+)/i
```

This matches one or more of either a letter (`a-z`), a digit(`\d`), or a space (`\s`).
The modifier `i` makes it match case insensitive.

Note that you can't use `\w` to match letters in this case, since it also matches the underscore which is explicitly disallowed in the OP's question.

Comment: Be warned that this will not give the desired result if the output contains numbers: "this is my 1 sting ; this is my 2 string , this is my 3 string" will return "this is my "

Comment: Thanks a lot. Another subquestion, how could I match the second string once I matched the 1st one and replaced it by empty '' ? So I will need to find every chain of words after the separator.

Comment: @SQB Please read [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20082476/remove-everything-within-script-and-style-tags#comment29919365_20082717)

Comment: @HamZa Updated accordingly. I've never actually worked with PHP _at all_, but I assumed PCRE. As _they_ say, assumption is the mother of all, ehr.... things that go wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Using `preg_replace`:

```
$string = 'This is a test string - This is a second test string ; This is a third test string';
$match = preg_replace('/[^\sa-z].*/i', '', $string);
echo $match; // => This is a test string
```

Comment: Works also, but a bit more complicated that the SQB's answer. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following Regex...

```
^[\w\s]*
```

Good Luck!

Comment: `\w` not only matches letters and digits, but also matches `_`.

Comment: \w should match alphanumeric characters

Comment: According to [PHP PCRE regex syntax - Escape sequence](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php), `\w` matches any "word" character. .... A "word" character is any letter or digit or the underscore character, that is, any character which can be part of a Perl "word".

Answer (score 0):

Check this regex, will find characters in all case with space

`/[A-Za-z\s]+/is`