# PHP regexp - put every word into the brackets

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I need to transform some string from:

```
big red car
```

to:

```
(big) (red) (car)
```

I know that I can do this with `explode()` and `implode()` functions or `foreach` cycle but I'm interested in a `regular expression` solution.

Comment: Do your strings contain anything else besides ASCII letters and space characters? If so, please show some examples (and what should happen with them). For example, how about a string like `"This is the 3rd déjà vu experience I've had"`?

Comment: You should consider running benchmarks on the implode/explode solution compared with the regex solution. Also, I'm interested in knowing more about what problem this question is actually trying to solve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`preg_replace()`](http://www.php.net/preg_replace) for this.

First match those words with:

```
\b(\w+)\b
```

Then replace with:

```
($1)
```

In PHP:

```
preg_replace('/\b(\w+)\b/', "($1)", $input);
```

Comment: Add the `g` flag for global replacement.

Comment: @Florent Thank you, I was editing the answer when you posted your comment.

Comment: There is no `g` modifier in PHP. Check my [previous comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20082476/remove-everything-within-script-and-style-tags#comment29919365_20082717)

Comment: @HamZa Thank you, I don't usually work with PHP so I didn't know that. Feedback appreciated.