# Extra hidden characters when trying to use php curl to get and parse JSON

Tags: php, json, curl

Here's my code:

```
$target_url = "http://myserver.localhost/get-questions-json.php?id=".$this->variable;
$ch = curl_init($target_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$assess_json = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

`echo $assess_json` displays:

```
[
    {
        "id": "345",
        "student": "19172",
        "question": "1031",
        "answer": "",
        "submitted": "0",
        "entry": "161235",
        "correct": "0"
    },
    {
        "id": "346",
        "student": "19172",
        "question": "1035",
        "answer": "",
        "submitted": "0",
        "entry": "161235",
        "correct": "0"
    },
    {
        "id": "347",
        "student": "19172",
        "question": "1052",
        "answer": "",
        "submitted": "0",
        "entry": "161235",
        "correct": "0"
    },
    {
        "id": "348",
        "student": "19172",
        "question": "1053",
        "answer": "",
        "submitted": "0",
        "entry": "161235",
        "correct": "0"
    },
    {
        "id": "349",
        "student": "19172",
        "question": "1050",
        "answer": "",
        "submitted": "0",
        "entry": "161235",
        "correct": "0"
    }
]
```

`echo strlen($assess_json)` displays 4078. If I copy and paste the string into PHP it says the length is 541.

`json_decode($assess_json)` is `NULL` while `json_decode($pasted_str)` is an object.

If I go directly to:
`http://myserver.localhost/get-questions-json.php?id=`, it shows the JSON string. The code is `echo json_encode($questions);`

So how can I get it to retrieve and parse the JSON properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit:

There are actually style and script tags in the string due to a PHP page that was included.
I used the following to fix it:

[Remove everything within script and style tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20082476/remove-everything-within-script-and-style-tags)

`$assess_json = preg_replace('/(<(script|style)\b[^>]*>).*?(<\/\2>)/is', "", $assess_json);`

Comment: I ended up putting <?php if (empty($for_api)) {?> around the style and script tags for the PHP that was included so the original problem stopped