# Is there any script like ckeditor that removes style and script when we paste code in textarea?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, ckeditor

Is there any script like **ckeditor**  that removes css and script when we paste code in a textarea? I want to remove css and script when user copy text from some where else and pastes it in my website

Comment: you want to only remove css and javascript? or all the html tag

Comment: only css and javascript like ckeditor is an example

Comment: there is no inbuilt function let me write code for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$myHtml = // here is your html;
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($myHtml);

removeElementsByTagName('script', $doc);
removeElementsByTagName('style', $doc);

$html = $doc->saveHtml();

function removeElementsByTagName($tagName, $document) {
  $nodeList = $document->getElementsByTagName($tagName);
  for ($nodeIdx = $nodeList->length; --$nodeIdx >= 0; ) {
    $node = $nodeList->item($nodeIdx);
    $node->parentNode->removeChild($node);
  }
}
```

*(code from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20082963/610573)*

Comment: in which variable i will get the final o/p

Comment: You will get final out put on `$html`

Answer (score -2):

Few alternatives to CKEditor. Check if they work for you.

http://redactorjs.com/

http://aloha-editor.org/

https://github.com/guardian/scribe

https://github.com/xing/wysihtml5

http://jhollingworth.github.com/bootstrap-wysihtml5/