# What's the quickest way to strip a string from a specific tag

Tags: php, regex

I have HTML in a string. I want to strip the `<head>` part of it. I use:

```
$html = preg_replace("/<head[^>]*?>.*?<\/head>/s", "", $html);
```

But in terms of performance, this can be a bit heavy. Is there a better alternative?

I know that I can use `strip_tags()` and list all accepted tags in the second argument but it's too many to list.

Comment: You could use `strpos()` to determine the position of the opening and closing `<head>` tag and then get the substring, but I am not sure if that's a better way to do it re performance.

Comment: You can write a better regex :) Like [`<head[^>]*?>[^<]*(?:<(?!\/head>)[^<]*)*<\/head>`](https://regex101.com/r/iY3cC5/2). Compare with [yours](https://regex101.com/r/iY3cC5/1).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew That's the one! Can you write up answer and explain how it decreases the steps etc. Very impressive. And can I add more tags in the same regex? Like `<head><header><nav>` so I remove all of them in one go rather than doing 3 separate reg_replace() runs.

Comment: Maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20082476/remove-everything-within-script-and-style-tags.

Comment: BTW, there are tags that can be nested, this approach will not work then. Fastest != safest.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew agree, even if a sax parser would probably be a quicer solution for this question

Comment: @ᴳᵁᴵᴰᴼ: sax is unfortunately very slow with PHP and can only be used with XML, (the same with XMLReader, (a pull parser from libxml that is from far faster)). But since it seems that the OP need to do several tasks on his html source, using DOMDocument isn't a problem, the cost of the tree building will be amortized.

Answer (score 0):

Your current regex takes 6720 steps when tested against part of this SO page.

This regex `<head[^>]*?>(?:[^<]*<??)*</head>` only takes 376 steps, and it should return the same thing. It should be almost 20x faster than your regex.

It works by greedily matching everything that's not `<` here: `[^<]*`

Then, because `<??` is lazy, it will try to immediately match `</head>`. If there is no match, the `<??` kicks in.