# How to remove html editors characters

Tags: php, html

Hello how to remove  html editors characters. For example numbered list, enter, lined list. I have used below code but cannot remove them

```
$content= htmlspecialchars_decode($content);
echo $content=strip_tags($content);
```

input is like

1. list 1
2. list2

I want output like: List1 list2

Comment: What is the input, what output are you expecting and what output are you actually getting?

Comment: Surely isn't this just CSS that's providing the output? If they're `<li>` items inside a `<ul>`, have you tried adding `list-style:none;` to the `<ul>` ?

Comment: When i see  the source from browser. There is no style and tags. I want to save them to show short description in search engine.

Answer (score 0):

All you need is strip tags. Your htmlspecialchars_decode() is overkill.

just do:

```
$html = "Html code";
$strippedHTML = strip_tags($html);
echo $strippedHTML;
```

Answer (score -1):

If your intention is to remove the html tags, you may want to check this 
[Regular expression to remove HTML tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3790681/regular-expression-to-remove-html-tags)

Edit:

Okay, referring to the link above and [php regex to remove HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/758806/php-regex-to-remove-html)

this may help

```
preg_replace('/<[^>]*>/', '', $content)
```